# Subreport not showing in master report after using same JSON Data Adapter

Tags: json, jasper-reports, subreport

Hello all I'm using the same JSON DataSource for both the Main and Sub Reports. The sub-report renders alone and shows the correct data, but when I render the main the sub-report is not showing. This project is using a DataAdapter to populate report data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Master Source:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.12.2.final using JasperReports Library version 6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b740c94e-e1f7-4c3f-923e-277307164214">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="DataAdapterDummyJSON.xml"/>
    <subDataset name="requiredDocuments" uuid="1da38f37-3954-4fc1-a49a-838d0998f903">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="JSON">
        <![CDATA[data]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="idcNumber" class="java.lang.Long">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="idcNumber"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[idcNumber]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cesco" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="cesco"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[cesco]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="digitalExpirationDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="digitalExpirationDate"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[digitalExpirationDate]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="licenseRenewalDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="licenseRenewalDate"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[licenseRenewalDate]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="reportCreationDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="reportCreationDate"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[reportCreationDate]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="firstName"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[firstName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="lastName"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lastName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="realId" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="realId"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[realId]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="requiredDocuments" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="requiredDocuments"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[requiredDocuments]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="finesCount" class="java.lang.Long">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="finesCount"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[finesCount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="finesTotal" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="finesTotal"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[finesTotal]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="lateFees" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="lateFees"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lateFees]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="finesDiscount" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="finesDiscount"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[finesDiscount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="transactionReceipt" class="java.lang.Long">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="transactionReceipt"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[transactionReceipt]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="charges" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="charges"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[charges]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="173" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="481" y="0" width="72" height="72" uuid="230d7b00-a7b1-4e3a-98d4-d5a5437233ad">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/QR_Code_Example.svg/1200px-QR_Code_Example.svg.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="80" width="595" height="30" uuid="504bf28a-d83a-46cd-a3c2-ea332dea2f45"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[RENOVACIÓN LICENCIA DE CONDUCIR]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="130" width="595" height="32" forecolor="#E7EAF3" backcolor="#E7EAF3" uuid="62dbd595-a135-4e3b-a57f-039a0fdd7d9e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="185" y="130" width="50" height="32" uuid="359d3e77-b483-4d15-80e4-317748044b4b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[IDC#:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="1" y="8" width="125" height="55" uuid="9a2c67f8-1838-44e0-9788-1596027bfe97">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["/ImageAssets/Logo_CESCO_Black_300-01.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="240" y="130" width="174" height="32" uuid="b5ce990b-316a-43d0-b1f9-1a82096ad25c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{idcNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="81" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="22" width="52" height="17" uuid="08447dfb-ae65-4263-85c7-23458503a2fe">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="14" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[FECHA: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="65" height="17" uuid="94542aaf-713f-44b2-85cd-4c53914a5ac7">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="14" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[CESCO: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="390" y="22" width="163" height="22" uuid="44fdaa70-e5d9-4f16-89d9-40dcb7302f3b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="14" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[EXPIRACIÓN DIGITAL: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="390" y="39" width="100" height="30" uuid="f03e03bc-216a-474d-beaf-0767385b6a49"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[03.28.2020]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="74" width="555" height="1" forecolor="#C3D0E6" backcolor="#C3D0E6" uuid="a8dc7c8b-5f54-4a51-bdae-175c0add0987">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="58" y="39" width="233" height="19" uuid="8b485199-6f49-4129-b332-7caa6e3f00a0">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cesco}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="mm.dd.yyyy">
                <reportElement x="57" y="21" width="156" height="19" uuid="d4f3b751-0dda-4af9-8a22-739986963bb3">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="21" width="196" height="38" uuid="5c2e2f49-ae7c-4e8b-803f-14b6247ddcba">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement markup="html">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="16" isBold="true" isItalic="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Fixed" lineSpacingSize="10.75"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Hermenegildo M. Maldonado Rodríguez]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="226" y="22" width="110" height="19" uuid="bedd6941-9ba3-4adb-9be7-225c01088cbc">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[CATEGORÍA:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="226" y="39" width="80" height="19" uuid="55f43612-d6f1-4abc-9dc8-2f60c068cab7">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[REAL ID:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="315" y="20" width="12" height="19" uuid="f1f43459-6647-4fbe-90fb-d0ea4f67163e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[3]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="288" y="38" width="18" height="19" uuid="11b6a3a0-04c0-40be-8710-6bde05720c79">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sí]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="390" y="21" width="165" height="19" uuid="aa23217e-9700-40d9-a258-83a3909aee2e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[EXPIRACIÓN LICENCIA²: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="390" y="37" width="100" height="19" uuid="aa7d5495-d928-4e94-b48e-05f4fbcac1bb">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[03.28.2020]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="77" width="555" height="1" forecolor="#C3D0E6" backcolor="#C3D0E6" uuid="42e5bb72-4f9a-4f83-8550-017bffcfd9b3">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="386" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1" y="19" width="552" height="22" uuid="5d45b4e5-f23a-4c44-bd87-caf78a955312">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Este comunicado también ha sido enviado a su correo electrónico. ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1" y="54" width="552" height="22" uuid="2712b163-8d9b-4de9-bc6b-b2bc8ecb01df">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Documentos necesarios para el recogido de la licencia:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="93" width="555" height="200" uuid="1935ef5e-f834-478a-9cc8-435f7a85418c"/>
                <subreport overflowType="NoStretch">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="200" uuid="c23cac66-6669-48fc-b3d4-a0bea131b3f7"/>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["RequiredDocuments.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="48" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="-2" y="-51" width="489" height="30" uuid="e7d65538-6c09-441b-b755-223d083d4b20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[De no tener algunos de estos documentos favor de seguir las instrucciones adjuntas. ]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

**Below the source for the sub-report:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.12.2.final using JasperReports Library version 6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="RequiredDocuments" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="4ede3a66-e567-4965-97b6-db3c2f081036">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="DataAdapterDummyJSON.xml"/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[data.requiredDocuments]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="documentNumber" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="documentNumber"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[documentNumber]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="title" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="title"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[title]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="instruction" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="instruction"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[instruction]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <group name="title">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{title}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="documentNumber">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{documentNumber}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="280" height="20" uuid="93e63c57-c041-43ce-9a1c-2607366a46c0"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{documentNumber} + ". " + $F{title}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Here is the JSON file I'm using for the report:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "idcNumber": 1234567890123,
    "cesco": "Sagrado Corazón",
    "digitalExpirationDate": "2020-04-07 09:27:45",
    "licenseRenewalDate": "2020-04-07 09:27:45",
    "reportCreationDate": "2020-04-07 09:27:45",
    "firstName": "Hermelegildo M.",
    "lastName": "Maldonado Rodríguez",
    "realId": false,
    "requiredDocuments": [
      {
        "documentNumber": 1,
        "title": "Este Documento Impreso o Digital",
        "instruction": "Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas \"Letraset\", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum."
      },
      {
        "documentNumber": 2,
        "title": "Licencia Actual",
        "instruction": "Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas \"Letraset\", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum."
      },{
        "documentNumber": 3,
        "title": "Seguro Social / Pasaporte",
        "instruction": "Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas \"Letraset\", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum."
      },{
        "documentNumber": 4,
        "title": "Recibo Agua, Luz, etc.",
        "instruction": "Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas \"Letraset\", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum."
      },{
        "documentNumber": 5,
        "title": "Foto y Firma Digitalizada",
        "instruction": "Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas \"Letraset\", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum."
      }

    ],
    "finesCount": 25,
    "finesTotal": 12000.00,
    "lateFees": 60.00,
    "finesDiscount": 60.00,
    "transactionReceipt": 120459593030,
    "charges": [
      {
        "chargeName": "Renovación Digital",
        "chargeAmount": 11.00
      },
      {
        "chargeName": "Renovación",
        "chargeAmount": 11.00
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post a sample JSON file to be used with those reports. And also, the simplified output that you expect to see after running them.

Comment: @Narcis hello, I updated the post with the JSON file I'm using. How can I obtain  the simplified output? The SubReport should just be a detail of the requiredDocuments list given by the expression on the sub-report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subreport needs to be properly connected to a data source, since `$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}` is `null` for any non-JDBC based connections:

```
<subreport overflowType="NoStretch">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="200" uuid="c23cac66-6669-48fc-b3d4-a0bea131b3f7"/>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("requiredDocuments")]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["RequiredDocuments.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Comment: I'm now trying to link another report that uses the data element (the same used in the master report) and It's not working. I'm using subDataSource("data")  should it work like that?